# Has anyone here used wapache ? Are there any alternative apache webserver with embedded browser stacks available

Tags: php, apache, browser

I came across wapache (http://wapache.sourceforge.net/) sounds like a very interesting project. But the development seems to have stopped on this one ... Does anyone know a stack which has apache webserver with controllable (at least partially) browser ?

Thanks

Comment: What's the task you are trying to solve? This project seems very meaningless to me. Why to have IE&Apache just to execute applications?

Comment: Perhaps he wants a portable server with inbuilt browser, for executing his applications locally... but i fear iam not aware of them.

Answer (score 0):

For those with same problem. I have use Wapache and it doesn't work with jQuery and CSS styles gets messed up. I was looking into this as I was also looking for similar way to convert my PHP Application to Desktop App. This can be achieved by using Portable Wamp (e.g ZWAMP). Those who are trying to do that, look into ZWAMP, etc.

Regards
ZeeV